# Documentação para um sistema

Tags: documentação

Estou em meio a produção de um sistema web, na verdade já quase no fim... A questão é que não foi desenvolvida qualquer documentação para o sistema, foi tudo sendo desenvolvido "diretamente", com base em um outro sistema antigo que a empresa tinha.

Como nunca fiz uma documentação, pesquisei bastante na internet, mas não consegui encontrar algo muito sólido a respeito. Muito se fala sobre diagramas de caso de uso, modelo relacional, descrição das classes e objetos e etc.

Queria saber se existe algum modelo que eu pudesse seguir como exemplo, pois não quero acabar fazendo algo que fique faltando coisas ou fique com coisas desnecessárias.

Como sei o que realmente deve estar na documentação e o que não precisa?

Achei também lugares falando sobre vários tipos de documentação, a do projeto, do sistema, do código, do banco de dados, do usuário, enfim... Não consegui entender direito como deve ser feito, se alguém puder me dar uma luz seria ótimo.

Comment: Desconheço qualquer coisa formal sobre o assunto. Pra ser bem sincero se nunca fez e não sabe nem do que se trata, provavelmente não é a pessoa adequada para isto. Eu imagino que a maioria das pessoas aprenderam como eu, vendo o que existe e copiando as ideias básicas, adaptando à sua necessidade. Tenho minhas dúvidas se é possível responder esta pergunta sem ser ampla, ou mesmo se isto faz parte da programação. Embora programadores façam isto intuitivamente, este é um trabalho de comunicação e não de programação. Veja isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94146/101

Comment: Qual é a finalidade da sua documentação? Qual é o público-alvo? Tem várias coisas diferentes que você pode chamar de "documentação".

Comment: @bfavaretto o cliente disse que quer a documentação para registrar o sistema e para fazer futuras alterações.

Comment: @bigown realmente não sou a pessoa adequada pra isso, mas não temos opções rs

Comment: E em qual linguagem está o seu sistema, e em que plataforma ele roda?

Comment: É um sistema web em PHP @bfavaretto